# How get bind Ble device list in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bind

I want to bind ble-device when connection. 
And when restart app, that reconnect ble-device where in binding list.

how connect ble-device with binding?
how get binding list?
if don't get bindin list, how connect device?

please, answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's too big area to explain with just answers. Start with reading https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth

Main classes are CBCentralManager, CBPeripheral, CBCharacteristic. Just for list device, `CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate`  would help.

Comment: I'm already doing connect device using didDiscover, didConnect, didDiscoverServices, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor and didUpdateValueFor. I thought it would get like android. but i don't know ios...